# Why is Accuracy and AUC is coming exactly same after applying Stratified K fold cross validation

Tags: machine-learning, data-science, evaluation, auc

I am new to machine learning and doing binary classification where accuracy and AUC is coming exactly same, I am not sure if that is ok or is there any problem.

Appreciate the help!!

Thanks

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I think the results suggested that the models could be overfitting or underfitting. The best way to do is to use a train-test split and check the results from the testing data.

Another reason could be your data size is small, and both models were able to overfit, so you definitely need a train-test split.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks for answering, I believe  k fold cross validation is better and can prevent overfitting compared to train test split ( that is hold out) . Is my understanding correct? I have tried hold out and I am getting different AUC and accuracy. But I wanted to apply k fold cross validation. What should i do?

Comment: What is the K, did you let the model see all the data? And don't you supposed to have a K results?

Comment: I have set K as 10, and calculating the mean accuracy and mean AUC

Answer (score 0):

If you see this high accuracys without any tuning, most of the time the baseline is also super high.

If you wanna have a good comparison you can built a dummy classifier, who always predicts the major class (classes in binary classifcation are 0 and 1), so you will predict always 1 and then do the accuracy testing. This will be your baseline, and if this is also 0,95 you know that this dataset is disbalanced and your classifier are not a good result.